# select an item from FlatList and pass the value to a variable state

Tags: javascript, react-native

After I render all the elements in my ListView I want to select one item and pass `item.text` value to `var { category }` but my code now is selecting all elements and have no clue how to pass the value. Any help?

```
_choosen(isSelected) {
  this.setState({
    selected: !isSelected,
  });
}
_categorySelected = () => {
  var { category } = this.state;
  console.log(category);
}
_renderList = ({ item }) => {
  let backgroundColor = this.state.selected ? "#000000" : "#ffffff";
  let fontWeight = this.state.selected ? "bold" : "normal";
  let showNext = this.state.selected ? "block" : "none";
  return (
    <TouchableHighlight
      selected={this.state.selected}
      onPress={() => this._choosen(this.state.selected)}
      underlayColor="#ffffff"
    >
      <View style={{ padding: 10, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
        <View style={{ backgroundColor: backgroundColor, width: 5, height: 25 }}></View>
        <Text style={{ marginLeft: 10, fontSize: 20, fontWeight: fontWeight }}>{item.text}</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableHighlight>
  );
}
```

Here is my `FlatList` list and `jobCategory` is upper in constructor

```
<FlatList
  style={{ marginTop: 20 }}
  data={this.state.jobCategory}
  renderItem={this._renderList}
/>
```

EDIT

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      jobCategory: [
        { key: '1', text: 'Barista & Bartender', value: 'Barista & Bartender' },
        { key: '2', text: 'Beauty & Wellness', value: 'Beauty & Wellness' },
        { key: '3', text: 'Careworkers & Health', value: 'Careworkers & Health' },
        { key: '4', text: 'Chef & Cook', value: 'Chef & Cook' },
        { key: '5', text: 'Cleaning', value: 'Cleaning' },
        { key: '6', text: 'Construction', value: 'Construction' },
        { key: '7', text: 'Driver & Courier', value: 'Driver & Courier' },
        { key: '8', text: 'Education', value: 'Education' },
        { key: '9', text: 'Events & Promotion', value: 'Events & Promotion' },
        { key: '10', text: 'Kitchen porter', value: 'Kitchen porter' },
        { key: '11', text: 'Office & Admin', value: 'Office & Admin' },
        { key: '12', text: 'Retail', value: 'Retail' },
        { key: '13', text: 'Sales & Marketing', value: 'Sales & Marketing' },
        { key: '14', text: 'Waiter or Waitress', value: 'Waiter or Waitress' },
        { key: '15', text: 'Warehouse', value: 'Warehouse' },
        { key: '16', text: 'Other', value: 'Other' }
      ],
      selected: false,
    };
    this._choosen = this._choosen.bind(this);
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two options: either you have an array of **selected states** for each and every item or then you "toggle" the state by passing an id of selected row.

Without knowing your whole structure, I'd recommend going with latter one:

in constructor:

```
this.state = {
  selectedItem: null,
};
```

and then in your functions:

```
_choosen(selectedItem) {
  this.setState({ selectedItem });
}

_renderList = ({ item }) => {
  const isSelected = (this.state.selectedItem === item.id);

  const backgroundColor = isSelected ? "#000000" : "#ffffff";
  const fontWeight = isSelected ? "bold" : "normal";
  const showNext = isSelected ? "block" : "none";

  return (
    <TouchableHighlight
      onPress={() => this._choosen(item.id)}
      underlayColor={"#ffffff"}
    >
      <View style={{ padding: 10, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
        <View style={{ backgroundColor, width: 5, height: 25 }}></View>
        <Text style={{ marginLeft: 10, fontSize: 20, fontWeight }}>{item.text}</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableHighlight>
  );
}
```

Of course this requires you actually have an *id / key* for your items (like you should have). If you have no identifying field, then this can also be achieved with `keyExtractor` by using index as a distinct value (which is not the best option):

```
<FlatList
  style={{ marginTop: 20 }}
  data={this.state.jobCategory}
  renderItem={this._renderList}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => `item-${index}`}
/>
```

Comment: have look on my constructor

Comment: It is selecting only one now but how do I pass the value of `selectedItem` in `category` variable from `__categorySelected`?